# Changed Default Map Route; can't get internal links to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I changed the maproute in my asp.net MVC4 application. It now looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{vendorname}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The user will always have to type a vendor in the URL for it to work. But now the internal links aren't working properly.

For example, if I direct to "/Manage/Account" it doesn't keep the vendor name in front, which makes it an invalid URL. I need them to maintain that first URL parameter. Where can I specify this? Thanks!

EDIT: The list of vendors could grow to hundreds at some point. They will be stored in an Organizations table in my database. Hardcoding them isn't an option.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you construct the url's on your page?

Comment: The url would be www.domainname.com/Vendor/Account/Manage. In my code, I just try to do hrefs to "/Account/Manage" because I need it to work for all of the available vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage Vendor Account", "Account", "Manage", new { vendorname = "vendor1" }, new { @class = "vendorlink" })
```

Which would link to "/Vendor1/Manage/Account".

If you need only the URL for a HREF you can do:

```
@Url.Action("Account", "Manage", new { vendorname = "vendor1" })
```

Comment: I've edited my question because this probably won't work for me. In this case, would I have to hard code every vendor? Because the list will constantly grow in my database and it could be hundreds at some point.

Comment: How do you know what vendor you're linking to? If you know it based on a session variable or user property or similar, just plug that value in where "vendor1" is provided above.

Comment: You would need to obtain the vendorname from whatever page has the link on it... most likely from a ViewModel of some sort or maybe even a hidden form field.

Comment: @swinkel: there must be, somewhere, some reference to the vendor. This can be in your viewmodel, the viewbag or even retrieved through an ajax call (some extra logic is needed in the latter). Anyhow, you dont need to hardcode every url. You can use a variable.

Comment: @EricKing yes! perfect. I do have a property for that and didn't even think of that. This + the original answer works for me.

Comment: @swinkel: one final remark on this issue: make sure that vendor `x` is unable to access vendor's `y`'s information by just changing the url ;-)